# Save the settings of a 3D view

Tags: qgis, 3d-map

**Is there a way to save the zoom, tilt, and orientation settings of a 3D map view in QGIS?**

QGIS version 3.10.

I have a 3D map view that I need to save as Image file (e.g. using the "Save as Image..." function).

I need to do this many times (once for each layer) and over different time periods.

I need the view geometry (zoom, tilt, and orientation) to be always **exactly the same** each time I save the image. Eventually, it would be nice to have more geometries saved and to be able to quickly switch from one to another.

Is there a way to save the zoom, tilt, and orientation settings so to reuse them later?

Comment: I think its not possible in 3.10. But have a look at visual changelog for newer versions (currently 3.24, with ver.  3.26 forthcoming shortly)